# I am trying to write VBA Script for running SAP T-code ZN_BSEG

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

Below is the details that are required to input

> Selection Criteria "Company Code"- Variable to pick from Cell A2
> Selection Criteria" Document Number"- Click Multiple Selection by
> Field then Copy Data from Cell C2  till last cell with data in Column
> C and paste using Upload from Clipboard Filed Name "Layout"- Use
> /1130020N Field Name "Maximum no. of hits"- Leave this field blank Now
> execute and export the file to "C:\Users\nitemit\Desktop\SDM
> Folder\1130020\ZN_BSEG.xlsx"

I am getting error code  "619 " for Company Code " session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BUKRS-LOW").Text = companyCode"

Below is the complete code

```
Option Explicit
Public SapGuiAuto, WScript
Public objGui As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession

Sub RunSAPTransaction()
    Dim companyCode As String
    Dim documentNumbers As String
    
    ' Get the company code from Sheet1, Cell A2 in the same workbook
    companyCode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
        
    ' Get the document numbers from Sheet1, starting from Cell C2 to the last cell with data in Column C
    documentNumbers = Join(Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2:C" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Value), ",")
    
    ' Connect to SAP
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
    Set session = objConn.Children(0)
    
    ' Maximize the SAP window
    session.findById("wnd[0]").Maximize
    
    ' Run transaction ZN_BSEG
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nZN_BSEG"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    
    ' Wait for the SAP session to be ready
    Do While session.ActiveWindow.Name = ""
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    
    ' Enter the company code
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BUKRS-LOW").Text = companyCode
    
    ' Click on "Multiple Selection by Field" for document numbers
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_BELNR-LOW").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtS_BELNR-LOW").caretPosition = 10
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 2
    
    ' Paste document numbers from clipboard
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[24]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[30]").press
    
    ' Wait for the SAP session to be ready
    Do While session.ActiveWindow.Name = ""
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    
    ' Choose layout /1130020N
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_LAYOUT").Text = "/1130020N"
    
    ' Leave Maximum no. of hits blank
    
    ' Execute the transaction
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
    
    ' Wait for the SAP session to be ready
    Do While session.ActiveWindow.Name = ""
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Loop
    
    ' Export the file to the specified location
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").PressToolbarButton "&MB_VARIANT"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&LOAD"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").CurrentCellColumn = "TEXT"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").selectedRows = "0"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ssubD0500_SUBSCREEN:SAPLSLVC_DIALOG:0501/cntlG51_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell").ClickCurrentCell
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").setCurrentCell 1, "BSCHL"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").contextMenu
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlRESULT_LIST/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
    
    ' Save the file
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_PATH").Text = "C:\Users\nitemit\Desktop\SDM Folder\1130020"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").Text = "ZN_BSEG.xlsx"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtDY_FILENAME").caretPosition = 11
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    
    ' Close SAP
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[15]").press
End Sub
```

Comment: First of all, nobody knows `ZN_BSEG` but you. Second, the error 619 means that the screen field doesn't exist in the screen behind `ZN_BSEG`. Stack Overflow is full of same questions, all going to the same direction that only you can fix it (i.e. the field name doesn't represent a field in the screen).

Answer (score 0):

First, I would test whether you can omit the dynamic loop.

e.g.

```
 . . .
 ' Wait for the SAP session to be ready
   'Do While session.ActiveWindow.Name = ""
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:04")
  'Loop

' Enter the company code
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BUKRS-LOW").Text = companyCode
. . .
```

Regards, ScriptMan